# Qt QTest segmentation fault at end of execution

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have a small test programs that talks to a server backend through a library that I have written. The test uses the QTest framework and runs through a bunch of test cases. The latest version of the test program has started to issue a segmentation fault after all of my tests have run. The output is something like:

```
********* Start testing of TestSequence *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.6.1, Qt 5.6.1 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10))

...

Totals: 28 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted
********* Finished testing of TestSequence *********

RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; real time: 26s; user: 40ms; system: 290ms
```

I can get a stack backtrace from the segfault:

```
#0  0x00007fffe9b3a61e in QDBusMetaType::typeToSignature(int) () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/bearer/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007fffe9b31a9e in qDBusParametersForMethod(QList<QByteArray> const&, QVector<int>&, QString&) () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/bearer/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007fffe9b31fc9 in ?? () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/bearer/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007fffe9aff081 in ?? () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/bearer/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007fffe9aff8bf in ?? () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/bearer/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007fffe9b005c6 in ?? () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/bearer/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007fffe9b115af in ?? () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/bearer/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00007ffff626cf7a in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00007ffff6242b6b in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00007ffff6245373 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x00007ffff6291d83 in ?? () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x00007ffff45f6e04 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#12 0x00007ffff45f7048 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#13 0x00007ffff45f70ec in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#14 0x00007ffff6292177 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#15 0x00007ffff6240bca in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#16 0x00007ffff607ae4c in QThread::exec() () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#17 0x00007ffff607f769 in ?? () from /home/pete/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#18 0x00007ffff4f19182 in start_thread (arg=0x7fffea796700) at pthread_create.c:312
        __res = <optimised out>
        pd = 0x7fffea796700
        now = <optimised out>
        unwind_buf = {cancel_jmp_buf = {{jmp_buf = {140737127212800, -4443015154407963459, 1, 0, 140737127213504, 140737127212800, 4443057989164074173, 4443034828799739069}, mask_was_saved = 0}}, priv = {pad = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, data = {prev = 0x0, cleanup = 0x0, canceltype = 0}}}
        not_first_call = <optimised out>
        pagesize_m1 = <optimised out>
        sp = <optimised out>
        freesize = <optimised out>
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = \"start_thread\"
#19 0x00007ffff57f047d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
No locals.
```

This looks like the fault is outside my code, but presumably something I've done has caused it!
Any insight from the crowd? Or should I report a bug to Qt?

Comment: You're not using a debug build of Qt, so the stacktrace is mostly useless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52988?focusedCommentId=325416&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-325416) bug that affects Qt 5.6.
As mentioned in the trail of comments, it should have been solved in Qt 5.7. You can also apply a few patches to solve it on version 5.6.
The discussion is dated 6/2016 and lasts at the end of September.

Comment: I think this is the case. I handed the project on to someone else (with a lot more Qt experience than I have) now so it's not my problem any more